# How to make Wordpress login page my home page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently using a plugin called *Members Only* to restrict certain users from accessing my site by redirecting them to the wp-login.php page.

My site's login url currently looks like this:
*http://localhost/home-page/login/*

Every time someone accesses a page before logging in the URL changes to this:
*http://localhost/home-page/login/?redirect_to=/home-page/*

Is there anyway to remove the */login/* section of the URL and have the login page's URL be:
*http://localhost/home-page/*?

Comment: u can use this plugin for this. https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/

Answer (score -1):

A quick way to accomplish this would be to make a [.htaccess rewrite rule](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php) to make h*ttp://localhost/home-page/ actually reference http://localhost/home-page/login/ and then in the admin panel of wordpress set up a custom homepage that actually represents what you want displayed after login.

Comment: That won't work… that'd make it impossible to access the "real" home page after logging in. (You'd just end up seeing the login page again.)

Comment: Hence the setting a custom home page.